# Clojure reader literal for float?

Tags: clojure

I was wondering why there is no clojure reader literal for floats. Something like:

```
1f
```

I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure-dev/0lc0ORfC_5g), but it has no responses. The clojure docs do not mention one either. Are there no plans to add it, and if not what is the rationale behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a matter of fact, there isn't a reader literal for 32-bit precisions integers either.

```
(class 1)
; => java.lang.Long

(class 1.0)
; => java.lang.Double
```

My guess is that it's an opinionated choice. 32-bits is so 20th century, it's time to move on. But you can still coerce to 32-bits types (and to short/byte as well), as @amalloy demonstrated.

Answer (score 2):

I usually just make sure it has a decimal point if I need to write a true float. `1.0` vs `1`

Comment: I meant to write this as a comment, not an answer, but there it is. Silly touchscreen.

Answer (score 1):

Clojure supports coercion to type float as defined [here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/float) and [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3353)

```
(def f1 (float 1))
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why there's no way do write a literal float (single-precision) that doesn't need coercion. Or is there?

Comment: you can also define a tagged literal or even use `#=(java.lang.Float/parseFloat "1")` in code (not in edn).

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answer from @omiel, you can write `1.` to get a float if you prefer a more terse syntax:

```
(class 1.)
; => java.lang.Double
```